# Drag/drop/scroll on mobiles between/within div blocks w/jQuery, and also block overall page scroll

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, scroll, drag

Situation:

1. Mobile phone equipped with jquery, jquery mobile, jquery-ui.touch and jquery.ui.touch-punch, the latter to make quite some things like drag/drop etc available for touch screens.
2. Two div blocks from which to drag bullets from one sortable div block into other sortable div block.
3. On the screen those two blocks are visually adjacent to one another to make things work although suboptimal, because bullet disappears when dragged into the other div block. Nevertheless it can be dropped somehow because afterwards bullets appear indeed in target div block and disappear in original div block.
4. With help of css option overflow: auto, one can make scrolling appear in both blocks to scroll through the list of bullets.

Problem:

1. These scrolling sometimes work and sometimes not because in the latter case either the whole page starts scrolling or (after clicking on local div scrollbar) it starts zooming-in to such a level/depth that the whole page becomes useless.
2. In Firefox Mobile div scrollbars not visible but scrolling sometimes possible; in Opera Mobile div scrollbars visible but at random "deeply" zooms in after clicking a div scrollbar.
3. Tried out different solutions given on the Internet to block page scrolling or zooming-in, but to no avail. Some "solutions" make page scroll is locked, but then either all scrolling is locked and/or dragging is also locked.

Question:

Anybody any experience with above situation or could give some hint? I know this is bleeding edge because even JQ/JQM (or any other framework?) has not reach this point at the moment, though they are working on it. 
jquery.ui.touch-punch is a plugin, although experimental, itś the only way I know so far who make drag/drop etc available for mobiles/touchscreens.

Thank you very much in advance!